# PostgreSQL daterange aggregation

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, overlap, date-range

I'm trying to get an aggregated data from one table, where there are two date columns (begin, end). I want to "merge" adjacent or overlapping rows. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Input

```
begin      | end    
-----------------------
2019-01-01 | 2019-01-31
2019-02-01 | 2019-03-15 -- adjacent to prev record
2019-03-01 | 2019-04-30 -- overlaps prev record
2019-10-01 | 2019-12-20
```

Desired output

```
begin      | end
------------------------
2019-01-01 | 2019-04-30
2019-10-01 | 2019-12-20
```

I'm able to do it using pl/pgsql, but I would like to do it using partitions and/or windows if possible. I tried to follow https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Range_aggregation but I didn't succeed.